# What does this operation mean? {| ... |} and +attrName

Tags: javascript, graphql

While looking thru graphql code, and came across this. Cannot search the operation and hope someone can tell me what it is? and what does it do?

`{| +name: string |}`

Found + in front of a variable means, parsing to number? but in this context is slightly weird. Unless they really want to convert it to number, but from the code, I don't think that is the intention.

[GraphQL code](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/blob/master/src/type/definition.js#L850-L859)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [flow syntax](https://flow.org/en/). You can tell by the `// @flow strict` at the beginning of the file.

`|...|` is the syntax for [exact object types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types). In you example, it means "name" should be the only property of the object.

`+...` is the syntax for [read-only property](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/interfaces/#toc-interface-property-variance-read-only-and-write-only).